# pip on OS X: installed 2.6 Python not recognizing modules installed with pip2.6

Tags: python, macos, pip, python-2.6, easy-install

With Python 2.6.8 and 2.7.10 (plus anaconda installs etc.) on my Mac, I needed to install **2.6.6 32-bit** (long story), so I installed it from dmg. With luck, when I then typed `python2.6` in a shell, the 2.6.**6** interpreter started (though only in that tab, not in others - perhaps this is significant?).

I then needed to install some modules, needing to make sure that they were got installed for this newly-in-place 2.6.6, not any other install. So I took the approach outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15878602/1389110), namely:

```
sudo easy_install-2.6 pip
```

I then installed my desired module using `pip2.6`:

```
sudo pip2.6 install py2app==0.5.2
```

When I went to run py2app using `python2.6`:

```
python2.6 setup.py py2app
```

It complained that setuptools was not installed. So as before,

```
sudo pip2.6 install setuptools
```

But once again:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Pyderman:projet Pyderman$ python2.6 setup.py py2app
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 98, in <module>
    mac_setup()
  File "setup.py", line 46, in mac_setup
    from setuptools import setup
ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

So .... `pip2.6` *is* installing modules, just not for 2.6.6. Is there a step I am missing, in order to ensure that python 2.6.6 is the default home for modules downloaded with `pip2.6`? Or is `pip2.6` the wrong approach here?

As requested:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Pyderman:project Pyderman$ which -a python2.6    
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6 
/usr/bin/python2.6 
/usr/local/bin/python2.6 

MacBook-Pro-de-Pyderman:project Pyderman$ which -a pip2.6 
/usr/local/bin/pip2.6
```

**Note: I will eventually move to using `pyenv` and/or `virtualenv`, but for now, I'm looking to achieve this without them.**

Comment: Just curious. It's 2016, why python 2.6.6?

Comment: Long story. A once-off requirement to build using 2.6.6.

Comment: pelase add the output of `which -a python2.6` and `which -a pip2.6`

Comment: @cel done, above. Odd though: I get a different output for `which -a python` in a different tab: `/usr/bin/python2.6
/usr/local/bin/python2.6`

Comment: You have 3 versions of `python2.6` installed. You may have to decide which one you actually want to use.

Comment: @cel as per the description: 2.6.6. I can live without the others.

Comment: Can you give the output of `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6  --version` and `echo PATH` from a freshly opened terminal?

Comment: @cel http://pastebin.com/6vBSGYkR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you, please open a new terminal for executing these commands:

```
cd /tmp
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6 get-pip.py
```

After that both `pip2.6` and `python2.6` should point to your 2.6.6 interpreter.

The command `which python2.6` should print

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6
```

The command `which pip2.6` should print

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/pip2.6
```

Comment: Thanks. Getting this though when I try execute get-pip.py: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6 get-pip.py` ..... *Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip*

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but `python` now starts the Python **2.6.6** interpreter, while `python2` starts Python **2.7.10**

Comment: @Pyderman, I added sudo in the last command. Bug from my side - sorry for that. I do not understand, why pip does not find a suitable version. Unfortunately, building 2.6.6 from the source is weirdly complex and requires a lot of hacks. I do not have the time/motivation to see if I can reproduce your error.

Comment: Adding `sudo` had no affect, I'm afraid. I appreciate your time and effort though, and if no-one else chimes in with a solution, the chosen answer will be yours.